# RadControl and Observable collection of dynamic object

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I have an `ObservableCollection` of `dynamic` objects that is bound to a `RadGridView`. I want to use the `RadDataFilter` control with this list. For some reason when I set the `Source` nothing appears as options for creating filtering rules.

You can see in the picture that the DropDown box that is supposed to have the names of the columns is empty.

[image]

I'm setting the source as follows

`DataFilter.Source = Data;`

`Data` is declared as `ObservableCollection<dynamic>`